# Why won't my image display after pulling from SourceTree with spatie media library in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree, laravel-medialibrary

I have a problem with the spatie media library where my image won't display after I pull it from a source tree. I don't know what the problem is. Is it a problem with spatie, or is it a problem with a source tree?

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Need some more detail. For example check your network tab and share what kind of error you are getting i.e. is it a 404 a 403 a 500 etc? Is the file located where you exepect it to and are the permissions ok (i.e. is it readable by the webserver). These sort of details will help

Comment: It's likely your uploads directory is in `.gitignore` (as it should be). Spatie media items shouldn't wind up in your Git repository at all, typically.

Comment: I think it has a problem with the image path; the path is not same with the image path that save in the database. But the problem occurs when I only pull it from Git and Sourcetree.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.